# What happens if you skip heart cinematics?

Tags: stardew-valley

Last time I was playing, I made it to 8 hearts with Maru, which prompted a scene outside of her house one night. According to [her wiki page](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Maru), the scene in question *was* the 8-heart scene.

As I looked into it a little more, I realized I missed the 4- and 6- heart scenes. Is it still possible to trigger these, or did I miss out on further relationship building?

Comment: The official Wiki seems to be incorrect. I have only 6 hearts with Maru and that scene just happened in my game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's been a few days, so I can finally say this with confidence, and Ross Ridge confirmed:

**The Wiki is wrong.**

I was only at 6 hearts when I viewed what was considered the 8-heart scene, and only got the 4-heart scene (according to the wiki) upon reaching 8 hearts. So it would seem that you are able to view the scenes in any order, so long as you have enough hearts to view a scene.